# Convert a column of int64 (YYYYMMDDHHMMSS) into datetime64 without delimiters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

this is the data in my pandas dataframe. i want to convert the **dateTime** column into a *datetime64* so i can check if duplicate **fileName** exist then find the file with the latest **dateTime**

as you can see the datetime format here is **YYYYMMDDHHMMSS** without delimiters

```
                      filePath        dateTime fileName
0  Line20170601142525_line1.dat  20170601142525    line1
1  Line20170601142525_line2.dat  20170601142525    line2
2  Line20170601142526_line2.dat  20170601142526    line2
3  Line20170601142526_line3.dat  20170601142526    line3

Process finished with exit code 0
```

This is my code

```
formattedFileDirectory['dateTime'] = pandas.to_datetime(formattedFileDirectory['dateTime'], format='%Y%M%d%H%m%S')
```

i get this error

```
TypeError: 'int' object is unsliceable
```

if i set the column as string i get this error

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you need to convert the dateTime column from `int` type to `string` type before you call `pd.to_datetime` on it.

If you get a ValueError about "unconverted data", it will usually tell you that either the string or the format you specified is bad. Try changing `'%Y%M%d%H%m%S'` into `'%Y%m%d%H%M%S'`. You can find the documentation on format strings [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) (scroll all the way to the bottom).

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you're looking for using [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['dateTime'] = df['dateTime'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x), format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))
```

If you don't like using `apply` because it's slow (cuz it's a loop) you could still use this:

```
df['dateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateTime'].astype(str),format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
```

output:

```
                       filePath            dateTime fileName
0  Line20170601142525_line1.dat 2017-06-01 14:25:25    line1
1  Line20170601142525_line2.dat 2017-06-01 14:25:25    line2
2  Line20170601142526_line2.dat 2017-06-01 14:25:26    line2
3  Line20170601142526_line3.dat 2017-06-01 14:25:26    line3
```

Comment: I would not suggest using `.apply()` on pd.to_datetime, as the function itself is well-equipped to handle a column of data. The `apply` method really is a for loop under the hood.

Comment: you're right, i updated @CaptainMeow, +1 for the idea