# Getting Error "cannot assemble the datetimes: 'int' object is unsliceable" while trying to apply pd.to_datetime(df)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am using this `DF(output_final_date)` which has columns:

```
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Year     481 non-null int32
Month    481 non-null int32
Day      481 non-null int32
dtypes: int32(3)
```

but when I apply the formula: 
`output_final_date['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(output_final_date)` -- I am getting below error :

> Error :- ValueError: cannot assemble the datetimes: 'int' object is
>   unsliceable

Comment: You need to convert the dataframe from `int32` to `string`. Check if this answer helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45028109/9025861.

Comment: I tried but its still not working                                                         
output_final_date['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(output_final_date[['Year','Month','Day']].astype(str),format='%Y%m%d%')     I am getting error - ValueError: format number 1 of "b'Feb 1978, 2, 1975 Total time of visit (in minutes):\n'" is not recognized

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data? `print(output_final_date.head())`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying column names when invoking `to_datetime()`?

```
output_final_date['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(output_final_date[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']])
```

It is also possible that you have encountered a variant of [this known bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26583) where the fucntion returns `TypeError` for invalid integer dates with %Y%m%d format. Make sure your Pandas installation is up-to-date.

Comment: I tried but its still not working                                                         
output_final_date['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(output_final_date[['Year','Month','Day']].astype(str),format='%Y%m%d%')     I am getting error - ValueError: format number 1 of "b'Feb 1978, 2, 1975 Total time of visit (in minutes):\n'" is not recognized